# Generate automatically a list of definitions (user-defined theorem environment) in appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, environments, appendices

In the following code, I define a theorem environment `definition` and write a figure and a definition:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[francais, english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\begin{figure}
a
\caption{haha}
\end{figure}
\begin{definition}[title]
  body
\end{definition}

% ------------------------------------------
% List of figures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
% ------------------------------------------
% List of Definitions
\chapter*{List of Definitions}
\markboth{List of Definitions}{List of Definitions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of Definitions}

\makeatletter
\@starttoc{lod}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

The `List of Figures` can be correctly generated in the appendix:

[image]

However, the `List of Definitions` is empty:

[image]

Does anyone know what to do to make the auto-generation of the list of definitions work?

**Edit 1:**
The solution of @egreg works fine for me in a separate file. When I adapt it to my huge tex files, I have got the following message while compilation. Could anyone help? (Sorry that I could not make the code simpler and copy here)

[image]

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74857/toc-like-list-of-definitions-using-theorem-environments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `thmtools` and `tocbibind`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[name=Definition]{definition}

\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Definitions}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\begin{figure}
a
\caption{haha}
\end{figure}
\begin{definition}[title]
  body
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
Body
\end{theorem}

% List of figures
\listoffigures

% List of Definitions
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=definition]

\end{document}
```

#### TOC page

[image]

#### List of definitions page

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works... But if I add `\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=theorem]`, the title of that page is still `List of Definitions`... How could I specify different titles for different lists?

Comment: I have got an error while adopting your solution to my tex files... Please see OP...

Comment: @SoftTimur You need to use `\declaretheorem` for this to work, not `\newtheorem`

Comment: I did use `\declaretheorem` instead of `\newtheorem`...

Comment: @SoftTimur Sorry, but it's impossible to say; try producing a MWE and add a new question.

Comment: Do you have any idea about my first comment (specifying different titles for different lists)? I don't think this has been addressed in the duplicate question either...

Comment: @SoftTimur You have to redefine `\listtheoremname` before using `\listoftheorems`