# Section Title in thmtools List of Theorems

Tags: etoolbox, thmtools

The `thmtools` package provides a `\listoftheorems` command that generates a list of theorems/definitions/etc.

Here's a MWE:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]

\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of definitions}

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={defn}]

\section{First Section}

\begin{defn}[Some definition]
definition text
\end{defn}

\section{Second Section}

\begin{thm}[Some Theorem]
theorem text
\end{thm}

\section{Third Section}

\begin{defn}[Another definition]
definition text
\end{defn}

\begin{defn}
definition without title
\end{defn}

\begin{thm}
theorem without title
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

**PROBLEM:** I'd like to display section names in the *List of definitions*. The desired effect would look roughly as follows:

> **1. First Section**
>
> 1.1 Definition (Some definition) ................................ 1
>
> **3. Third Section**
>
> 3.1 Definition (Another definition) ............................ 1
>
> 3.2 Definition ........................................................... 1

I've been trying to adopt the suggestions of [this excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74874/72170), but with little success. The suggested solution is a patch (via `etoolbox`) to the `\thmtlo` command from `thmtools` that annotates chapter breaks in the `.loe` file; the difficulty lies in that `\thmtools` has no equivalent command for annotating sections. Looking at the `\thmtools` [documentation](http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/thmtools/thmtools.pdf), the relevant command is defined on page 29, line 770. My naive attempt was to emulate that chunk of the code in the preamble of the MWE, in which I essentially just replace every occurrence of "chapter" with "section"; i.e., include the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thmtlo@oldsection{0}%
\newcommand\thmtlo@sectionvspacehack{}
\ifcsname c@section\endcsname
  \ifx\c@section\relax\else
    \def\thmtlo@sectionvspacehack{%
      \ifnum \value{section}=\thmtlo@oldsection\relax\else
            \addtocontents{loe}{\protect\thmlopatch@endsection\protect\thmlopatch@section{\thesection}}%
        \xdef\thmtlo@oldsection{\arabic{section}}%
      \fi
}%
    \fi
\fi
\makeatother
```

Sadly, this doesn't work at all, as the `.loe` file remains unchanged.

Comment: `thmtools` does a weird stuff there ... :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, Indeed. What is your feeling about it? Is what I'm asking impossible to implement with `thmtools`?

Comment: Not impossible, but extremely difficult. I suspect, it's easier to build the `\listoftheorems `on your own, with `tocloft`, for example. I'll try to provide a solution, but it will take time

Answer (score 1):

if you are still trying to solve this question, I found a way.

First, in the thm-listof.sty file you have to comment out this line:

```
\addtocontents{loe}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
```

then, using etoolbox (and probably some other package I forgot), add this in the header of your .tex file:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thischaptertitle{}\def\thischapternumber{}
\newtoggle{nothms}

\apptocmd{\@chapter}%
  {\gdef\thischaptertitle{#1}\gdef\thischapternumber{\thechapter}%
    \global\toggletrue{nothms}}{}{}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{definition}{%
    \iftoggle{nothms}{
      \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}%
        {\protect\numberline {\thischapternumber} {\thischaptertitle}}{}{} }
      \global\togglefalse{nothms}
    }{}
  }%
}

\makeatother
```

Which works as long as the first entry in the chapter is a definition. Once I finished writing my thesis, I might add a working example.

Comment: This seems to focus on adding a *chapter* title rather than a *section* title (as requested by the OP). Additionally, how would you handle *sections* that don't have a `definition` in them?