# Creating a List of Theorems divided into Subsections with amsthm

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, theorems, amsthm, etoc

I want to modify the `listoftheorems` command so that at the end of each chapter, I can give a list of the theorems or definitions within the last chapter, and I want these divided by section (it should look like the ToC with bolded section headers and then theorem/definition listings underneath). I am using amsthm and I want it to look a bit like [ToC like list of definitions (using theorem environments)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74857/toc-like-list-of-definitions-using-theorem-environments) (except with sections instead of chapters, and I want it to be generated at the end of each chapter).

My current setup is,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

% defining theorem environment
\declaretheorem[
numberwithin = section,
]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[
sibling=theorem,
]{definition}

\begin{document}

\chapter{TEST}

\section{First Section}

\begin{theorem}
This shouldn't be included in the list of theorems from chapter two
\end{theorem}

\chapter{Test}

\section{test}

\begin{definition}[test definition 1]
Test definition
\end{definition}


\begin{theorem}
Best theorem
\end{theorem}

\section{The next section}

\begin{theorem}
Test 2
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Test 3
\end{theorem}

Now here I want to add a list of the theorems from the last two sections.

\end{document}
```

I've tried without success to modify the `listoftheorems` command and adapt solutions from other threads to my need. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, can you complete your code to make a small but complete document, including `\documentclass` and `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` with at least a dummy chapter and section.Then it will be easier for people to play with it and help you.

Comment: Also, your theorem style is not really pertinent to the problem (colour etc.) so you could also simplify the code a bit too.

Comment: Okay, @AlanMunn I updated the post with a working piece of test code. I at first didn't include a full document because I use a large number of packages and most or all of them probably won't affect the solution, but one previous solution I used interfered with the use of hyperref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

% defining theorem environment
\declaretheorem[
numberwithin = section,
]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[
sibling=theorem,
]{definition}

\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetlevel{theorem}{6}

\AtEndEnvironment{theorem}{%
  \etoctoccontentsline{theorem}{\protect\numberline{\thetheorem}}%
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mylocallistoftheorems}[1]{%
  \begingroup
% per lazyness we are going to use the default chapter style for rendering
% sections, but the space for the number is then too short
% use tocloft's commands for easier customization
  \patchcmd{\l@chapter}{1.5em}{2em}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\l@section}{1.5em}{2em}{}{}%
% make regular subection invisible
  \etocsetlevel{subsection}{6}%
% pretend theorem in TOC is like subsection
  \etocsetlevel{theorem}{2}% subsection
% make section (the top level local to chapter) be rendered in TOC like
% a chapter. Needs etoc 1.08k [2017/09/28] for \etocsavedchaptertocline
% else we can do manually saving \l@chapter before usage
  \etocsetstyle{section}
    {}
    {}
    {\etocsavedchaptertocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}
    {}%
  \etocsetstyle{theorem}
    {}
    {}
% this will be rendered like a non-numbered section, but we could have used
% \numberline here also
    {\etocsavedsectiontocline{Theorem \etocnumber}{\etocpage}}
    {}%
% not deeper than theorem (= subsection)
% top level is anyhow section, as we are local to a chapter
  \etocsetnexttocdepth{theorem}%
% avoid the global book style which does a \clearpage
  \etocarticlestyle
% self-explanatory
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{List of theorems of this chapter, per sections}%
% goes in pair with \invisiblelocaltableofcontents\label{foobar}
% right after \chapter command
  \tableofcontents\ref{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{TEST}

\section{First Section}

\begin{theorem}
This shouldn't be included in the list of theorems from chapter two
\end{theorem}

\chapter{Test}
\invisiblelocaltableofcontents\label{tocchap2}

\section{test}

\begin{definition}[test definition 1]
Test definition
\end{definition}


\begin{theorem}
Best theorem
\end{theorem}

\section{The next section}

\begin{theorem}
Test 2
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Test 3
\end{theorem}

Now here I want to add a list of the theorems from the last two sections.

\mylocallistoftheorems{tocchap2}

\end{document}
```

I have added hyperref for clearer demonstration.

[image]

It would be possible using `\etoclink` to get the hyperref link to theorems include the word `Theorem`.