# Increase spacing between paragraphs

Tags: spacing, environments

I wrote a small environment to write exercises:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\listofexercises}{List of exercises}
\newlistof{exercise}{exp}{\listofexercises}

% Restart counter at each new chapter
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{exercise}{chapter}
\makeatother

% Exercise environment
\newenvironment{exercise}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{exercise}
    \par\noindent\textbf{Exercice \thechapter.\theexercise} {#1}
    \newline
    \addcontentsline{exp}{exercise}{%
        Exercice \thechapter.\theexercise
        \ifx&#1&\else\ -- #1\fi
    }\par
}{
    \newline%
}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Foo}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{exercise}
What is the difference between a duck?
\end{exercise}

\lipsum[2][1-3]

\begin{exercise}
What is the answer to life the universe and everything?
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[Don't answer yes]
Are you human?
\end{exercise}

\chapter{Bar}

\begin{exercise}[Impossible?]
If you enjoy wasting time, is that time really wasted?
\end{exercise}

\backmatter

\listofexercise

\end{document}
```

Sadly, the spacing doesn't help to clearly identify the exercise. The parindent are confusing and the spacing is not great.

[image]

Some workaround would set no parindent for the whole document and add a double `\newline` after the environment, but I don't think it is a good solution.

Moreover if I add a new line after an exercise I get an error. With this:

```
\begin{exercise}
What is the answer to life the universe and everything?

\end{exercise}
```

I get this:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.44 \end{exercise}
```

Comment: I think a better way is to make an example environment like that derives from a theorem environment using `\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]` or similar. If you want you own list of these you can see some of the solutions here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74857/106804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this can be done in a prettier way. My first idea was something like this.

Instead of just the `par`-command you could use `\par\addvspace{\baselineskip}`:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand{\listofexercises}{List of exercises}
\newlistof{exercise}{exp}{\listofexercises}

% Restart counter at each new chapter
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{exercise}{chapter}
\makeatother

% Exercise environment
\newenvironment{exercise}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{exercise}
    \par\addvspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\textbf{Exercice \thechapter.\theexercise} {#1}
    \par
    \addcontentsline{exp}{exercise}{%
        Exercice \thechapter.\theexercise
        \ifx&#1&\else\ -- #1\fi
    }\par
}{
    % \newline%
}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Foo}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{exercise}
What is the difference between a duck?
\end{exercise}

\lipsum[2][1-3]

\begin{exercise}
What is the answer to life the universe and everything?
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[Don't answer yes]
Are you human?
\end{exercise}

\chapter{Bar}

\begin{exercise}[Impossible?]
If you enjoy wasting time, is that time really wasted?
\end{exercise}

\backmatter

\listofexercise

\end{document}
```

[image: baselineskip in exercise]