# List of Theorems divided by Chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems, thmtools

I'm trying to divide my list of theorems by chapter, similar to what is done in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74857/toc-like-list-of-definitions-using-theorem-environments?noredirect=1&lq=1). I'm using the `thmtools` package, and I'm quite close of getting it to work. I've used the following code from the link I posted:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{lightgray!25}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]

\newtheoremstyle{definitionsty}{3pt}{3pt}{\slshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{definitionsty}
\newtheorem{tdefn}{Definition}[chapter]
\newenvironment{defn}
  {\begin{shaded}\begin{tdefn}}
  {\end{tdefn}\end{shaded}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\thmtlo@chaptervspacehack
  {\addtocontents{loe}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
  {\addtocontents{loe}{\protect\thmlopatch@endchapter\protect\thmlopatch@chapter{\thechapter}}}
  {}{}
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{loe}{\protect\thmlopatch@endchapter}}
\long\def\thmlopatch@chapter#1#2\thmlopatch@endchapter{%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{#2}%
  \ifdim\ht\z@>\z@
    \hbox{\bfseries\chaptername\ #1}\nobreak
    #2
    \addvspace{10\p@}
  \fi
}
\def\thmlopatch@endchapter{}

\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thmtformatoptarg}[1]{ -- #1}
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of definitions}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={tdefn}]

\mainmatter
\chapter{X}

\begin{defn}[My hilarious definition]
bla bla
\end{defn}

\chapter{Y}

\begin{thm}
b
\end{thm}

\chapter{Z}

\begin{defn}[My hilarious definition 2]
bla bla
\end{defn}

\begin{thm}
a
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The only "problem" with this solution is that I'd like to have the full chapter name, not only the number. How does one modify this code in order to achieve this? I've tried tweaking this code by my-self, but I was not able to get it working.

Comment: `\thmtlo@chaptervspacehack` doesn't have access to the chapter name.  It is called by every theorem and checks for changes in the chapter counter.  The advantage of this approach is that chapters without theorems don't get listed.  You also need to hack `\@chapter` to store the title (#1 short, #2 long) into a global macro.

Comment: All my chapters actually have theorems, so is there a way to get it working in such case?

Answer (score 1):

Saves the chapter title into `\chaptertitle`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{lightgray!25}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]

\newtheoremstyle{definitionsty}{3pt}{3pt}{\slshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{definitionsty}
\newtheorem{tdefn}{Definition}[chapter]
\newenvironment{defn}
  {\begin{shaded}\begin{tdefn}}
  {\end{tdefn}\end{shaded}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\chaptertitle}{}% reserve global name
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\chaptermark{#1}}{\chaptermark{#1}\xdef\chaptertitle{#1}}{}{}
\patchcmd\thmtlo@chaptervspacehack
  {\addtocontents{loe}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
  {\addtocontents{loe}{\protect\thmlopatch@endchapter\protect\thmlopatch@chapter{\thechapter~\chaptertitle}}}
  {}{}
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{loe}{\protect\thmlopatch@endchapter}}
\long\def\thmlopatch@chapter#1#2\thmlopatch@endchapter{%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{#2}%
  \ifdim\ht\z@>\z@
    \hbox{\bfseries\chaptername\ #1}\nobreak
    #2
    \addvspace{10\p@}
  \fi
}
\def\thmlopatch@endchapter{}

\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thmtformatoptarg}[1]{ -- #1}
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of definitions}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={tdefn}]

\mainmatter
\chapter{X}

\begin{defn}[My hilarious definition]
bla bla
\end{defn}

\chapter{Y}

\begin{thm}
b
\end{thm}

\chapter{Z}

\begin{defn}[My hilarious definition 2]
bla bla
\end{defn}

\begin{thm}
a
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

---

This version adds every chapter, not just the ones with theorems.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{lightgray!25}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]

\newtheoremstyle{definitionsty}{3pt}{3pt}{\slshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{definitionsty}
\newtheorem{tdefn}{Definition}[chapter]
\newenvironment{defn}
  {\begin{shaded}\begin{tdefn}}
  {\end{tdefn}\end{shaded}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\chaptertitle}{}% reserve global name
\makeatletter
\let\thmtlo@chaptervspacehack\relax
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\chaptermark{#1}}{\chaptermark{#1}%
  \addtocontents{loe}{\par\noindent\textbf{\@chapapp~\thechapter~#1}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thmtformatoptarg}[1]{ -- #1}
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of definitions}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={tdefn}]

\mainmatter
\chapter{X}

\begin{defn}[My hilarious definition]
bla bla
\end{defn}

\chapter{Y}

\begin{thm}
b
\end{thm}

\chapter{Z}

\begin{defn}[My hilarious definition 2]
bla bla
\end{defn}

\begin{thm}
a
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it didn't work. Still the same thing is showing :(

Comment: All my chapters will have theorems. Thus, is there an easy way to get it to work?

Comment: Did you run it twice?  And yes, there is a simpler solution if you want every chapter to appear.

Comment: Yeah, I've run it twice :/

Comment: Are you using a package like titlesec?  It replaces \@chapter with something else.

Comment: I was. I tried removing it, but still nothing :(

Comment: Without knowing what is different about your code from my solution, I can't help you.  I just looked over the titlesec code again, and I still can't make sense out of it.