# Custom table of contents for Theorems in LaTeX Document

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, hyperref, overleaf, automation

I'm creating a LaTeX document (on Overleaf) filled with mathematical theorems and proofs. To quickly overview which theorems have been proven, I need a custom table of contents (TOC) that organizes theorems under specific headings at the beginning of the document. I've defined a command:

```
\newRegister{Content}{Heading}
```

to mark theorem statements. Content is a brief description or name of the theorem, and

**Heading** is the category. The TOC should list these under their **Heading**, with clickable

**Content** leading to their location in the document.

Example entries:

```
\newRegister{In1}{Headline1}
\newRegister{In2}{Headline1}
\newRegister{In3}{Headline3}
```

The TOC should automatically organize and display them as:

```
Headline1
    In1
    In2
Headline3
    In3
```

How can I implement a dynamic, clickable TOC based on \newRegister entries?

Thanks for any guidance!

I can manually make the TOC with following code. But is their a more general approach for command \printRegister whitch allows me to insert any kind of headline and formula (e.g. \newRegister{in4}{Headline4} in the document tag) without any more adjustment of the command \printregister?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\newRegister}[2]{
    \noindent\hyperlink{#1}{#1}\\
    \hypertarget{#1}{}
}

\newcommand{\printRegister}{
    \section*{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
    \noindent\textbf{Headline1}\\
    \newRegister{In1}{Headline1}
    \newRegister{In2}{Headline1}
    \noindent\textbf{Headline3}\\
    \newRegister{In3}{Headline3}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \printRegister
    
    \section*{Theoreme}
    
    \subsection*{Headline1}
    \newRegister{In1}{Headline1}
    some content
    
    \newRegister{In2}{Headline1}
    some more content
    
    \subsection*{Headline3}
    \newRegister{In3}{Headline3}
    content
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `\listoftheorems`  from `thmtools` (with two different theorem environment for proven and not which share the same names and counters)?

Comment: Some possibilities in that vein: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74857/107497

Comment: Can you explain why the suggested solutions don't do what you want? Why aren't you using any of the existing packages for managing theorems?